Reverse the order of parenthetically grouped text and reverse the order of parenthetical groups
I have a strings with pattern, something like this:
(X,1,1,3),(X,1,1,3),(X,@2,@2,@2,@2,@2,(Y,1))

And I need to extract from this One big array, reverse order, and generate new string:
(X,(Y,1),@2,@2,@2,@2,@2),(X,3,1,1),(X,3,1,1)

And expected array:
Array (
    [0] => Array(
        [parent] => (X,1,1,3)
        [childs] => Array(
            [0] => X
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 3
        )
    [1] => Array(
        [parent] => (X,1,1,3)
        [childs] => Array(
            [0] => X
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 3
        )
    [2] => Array(
        [parent] => (X,@2,@2,@2,@2,@2,(Y,1))
        [childs] => Array(
            [0] => X
            [1] => @2
            [2] => @2
            [3] => @2
            [4] => @2
            [5] => @2
            [6] => (Y,1)
        )
)

For now, I have only first level for parents with this code:
   foreach($datasetxml->Solution->Pattern as $el){

        if(substr( $el["Str"], 0, 1 ) === "L"){

            preg_match_all("/\((((?>[^()]+)|(?R))*)\)/", $el["Str"], $text);

            $text = $text[0];

            $text = array_reverse($text);
            
            foreach($text as $t){            
                //$t = str_replace(")", "", $t);
                $new_texts[] = $t;            
            }        
            $new_text = implode(",", $new_texts);        
            $el["Str"] = $new_text;
        }    

    }


Regular expressions aren't good at handling nested patterns like this.

It always helps to know more about input data other than it looking like "something". It seems quite regular: There's an X or Y at the beginning of what seems to be an array, followed by numbers, separated by commas, and optionally preceded by an @. This all has probably some kind of meaning, and maybe there won't be something like (X,1,"a,b,c",1,3), but we don't know, because you didn't tell us.

There's an X or Y at the beginning, followed by numbers, separated by commas, and optionally preceded by an @. Sometimes, instead of numbers, there can be group like this (Y, 1, 2) - and the same rules apply for this.. X or Y at the beginning, followed by numbers, separated by commas, and optionally preceded by an @

Don't you want to parse nested levels too?

in the future yes, but for now it is not required

There is too much of a disconnect between your sample data and your code.  if(substr( $el["Str"], 0, 1 ) === "L"){ doesn't make any sense with your sample data.

I could reverse you pattern by converting it to JSON, then decode and manipulate it. The code looks like this:
<?php

function reverseRecursive($array, $recursing = false) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $array[$key] = '(' . reverseRecursive($value, true) . ')';
        }    
    }
    $first = $recursing ? array_shift($array) . ',' : '';
    return $first . implode(',', array_reverse($array));
}

$data    = '(X,1,1,3),(X,1,1,3),(X,@2,@2,@2,@2,@2,(Y,1))';
$json    = preg_replace(['/[^(),]+/', '/\(/', '/\)/'], 
                        ['"$0"', '[', ']'], "($data)");
$inverse = reverseRecursive(json_decode($json));

echo $inverse;

This results in:
(X,(Y,1),@2,@2,@2,@2,@2),(X,3,1,1),(X,3,1,1)

A demo can be found here: https://3v4l.org/kISpv
preg_replace() is used to turn your pattern into JSON. This is then decoded so it can be processed in PHP. The reverseRecursive() does a basic recursive reverse of the array, leaving the first item in place except for the outer array, and implodes it to a string again.

preg_filter() is appropriate to call when you not only wish to sanitize the characters, but also wish to disqualify/remove a whole data point (function may be used on a string or an array).  If I am understanding your coding intention, you do not want to reduce the substring to null if there is a failure to make matches.  I believe you should be using preg_replace() here.  Please correct me if I am wrong. Relevant reading: preg_replace() versus preg_filter()

The ( and ) in the character class do not need to be escaped.  The first pattern doesn't benefit from being wrapped in a capturing group.  I recommend curly braces on the if for PSR-12 compliance.  I might've made $value modifiable by reference, but that is more of a personal choice.

@mickmackusa Yes, preg_replace() also works, and is indeed more appropriate, changed that. I'm certainly not a regex expert, I was happy it worked, but shorter is better, and the curly braces should definitely be there. For those who want to see the version of the answer MickMackUSA is talking about: Hit the "edited ..." link, in the middle under the answer, to see it.

I don't know how well this will hold up on varied input, but it is designed to be recursive in its splitting, reversing, imploding behavior while preserving the first entry's position in each parenthetical group.
The first regex isolates the parent level parenthetical segments and removes the outer parentheses. The second regex isolates the children on the next level. The first child is separated because it is not to be repositioned. Any remaining children are potentially recursively processed, then all children are reversed and appended to the first child. Finally, all parent level segments (with their reversed children) have their order reversed and are re-wrapped with parentheses.
I am fairly confident that this task is going to be too niche to help other developers.
Code: (Demo)
function rSplitReverse($string) {
    preg_match_all("/\(((?:(?>[^()]+)|(?R))*)\)/", $string, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[1] as &$m) {
        if (preg_match_all("/(\((?:(?>[^()]+)|(?R))*\))|[^(),]+/", $m, $items, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
            $first = array_shift($items)[0];
            foreach ($items as &$item) {
                $item = isset($item[1]) ? rSplitReverse($item[0]) : $item[0];
            }
            $m = "$first," . implode(',', array_reverse($items));
        }
    }
    return '(' . implode('),(', array_reverse($matches[1])) . ')';
}

echo rSplitReverse('(X,1,1,3),(X,1,1,3),(X,@2,@2,@2,@2,@2,(Y,1))');
// (X,(Y,1),@2,@2,@2,@2,@2),(X,3,1,1),(X,3,1,1)


I like the use of &$m and &$item in the loops. It removes the need for having the key present.
